# Docker-Pythonscript not working in container

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have a python script which works perfectly when i run it locally at my pc.However,when i built a docker container with the python script,the dockerfile and the requirements.txt file and tried to run it from docker,it doesn't work.More specifically i get an error when i use the json.load() or json.loads() function.Here is a sample of my code:

```
import requests
import json
import sys
import os

some code...

with open('output.json', 'r') as f:
  json_data = json.load(f)
```

I get this error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How is it possible that the python script works fine when i run it from my terminal and it gives me such an error when i run it from the docker container?

Comment: How your `output.json` generate, use `requests` to get some `url`, maybe docker network issue? You may need first assure your network is ok.

Comment: You are right.i use requests to get some url,download some data from a rest api.The output.json is generated here:
    output_file = sys.argv[2]
with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
      output.write(result)
sys.argv[2] is an argument i use to declare which will be the output file
In this case,its name is output.json since the result is of json format

Comment: it is not a pure python question, seems with more complex environment issue, we can not help you, just can give you some suggestion, why not enter into the container and have a test for every part of your thing, network, output json file, check one by one.

Comment: How am i going to do that testing in every part?As for the output.json i have founf the tmp folder where it is generated and the file is just fine

Comment: your json file is stored in some place of your container? Then, why not start python repl in your container & execute `json.load` in repl to narrow the cause of this issue?

Comment: I solved it.The problem was that every time i use a file either for reading or writing,even if i have used it before,i have to pass its name as an argument through docker.Thanks for your help!